# Add Form parameters to url Play framework

Tags: url-rewriting, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am developing an application with Play Framework version 2.1

I have a form in one of my scala view files, jut like following :

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Users.formHandle("title")) {
<fieldset>

@select(
    firstForm("country"), 
    options = options(Country.listAll),
    '_default -> "--- Choose a country ---",
    '_showConstraints -> false,
     '_label -> "country",               
)

@select(
    firstForm("state"), 
    options = options(State.listAll),
    '_default -> "--- choose your state ---",
    '_showConstraints -> false,
    '_label -> "state",               
)                                        
}
```

And in the routes file I have:

```
GET  /submit  controllers.Users.formHandle(String : sen)
```

Obviously after submitting the form the url will be like:

```
host/submit?country=nameOfTheCountry&state=nameOfTheState
```

How can I change the above url into:

```
host/submit/nameOfTheCountry/nameOfTheState
```

anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

When the web browser submits a form with the `GET` method, it puts all the parameters into the query string - that's the HTML spec.  You cannot make it do anything else.  If you want it to do something else, then you'll have to use JavaScript to intercept the form submission, and manually build the URL in JavaScript yourself, then set the window location to that URL.

Comment: I don't want and I can't change the spec of HTTP I am just looking for a way to circumvent this limitation,

Comment: So attach an `onsubmit` callback to the form that takes the parameters out of the form and builds the URL, eg using jquery it will look something like this: $("#myform").submit(function(e) { window.location = "/submit/" + $("#country").val() + $("#state").val() ; e.preventDefault();});

Comment: my approach currently is explained in the answers in this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843365/get-request-parameter-with-play-framework/20792955#20792955
what do you think which approach you recommend a redirect or using javascript?

Comment: Which is best depends on what you're trying to achieve.  In the solution you linked to, the client makes two requests, one that gets redirected, and then the actual request.  I don't see the point in that, why not just handle it in the first request, two requests means it's going to take twice as long for the user to see the result?  But then the answer may be in your reason for wanting a particular URL format... and I don't know why you care about the URL format, so I can't answer that.